# How to design a writing assistive system that can do writing style guide check like how Grammarly does for gramma checking

Tags: sequence-to-sequence, llm

I have a style guide that specifies the use of punctuations, line length, and how to break up a line (e.g. before prepositions). I have a dataset that contains original text and the version of the text are conformed to this style guide.

Now, how do I design a system that can recommend to user how to conform a given text to the style guide? More specifically,

- How do I frame this task as?  Is this a type of sequence-to-sequence modeling task?
- Is fine-tuning a LLM with my data a good approach? How to deal with hallucinations?
- How can this system also tell users that what style guide rules are used in the recommendations?